# Dynamically Generate SQL for Logical Sentence

Tags: sql, dynamic-programming, dynamic-sql, postgresql-11

Super tricky question. I have a client wanting to output `true/false` based on a string sentence that represents a `rule`.

E.g. if a rule is the string: `"56 AND 78"`, then this means "Return `true` if `Table A` has rows with ID `56` and ID `78`. Note that it doesn't mean the same row has ID `56` and `78` as that's not possible.

Now, I could go ahead and dynamically generate some pseudo SQL like below for the simple cases:

```sql
RETURN QUERY (SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                            FROM table_a
                            WHERE id = 56)
              AND
              SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                            FROM table_a
                            WHERE id = 78))
```

where the `WHERE` clauses are generated directly from the `rule`. This satisfies the simple sentence.

However, the rules can get far more complex.
E.g. `"(43 OR 44 OR 47) AND (2182 OR 2179 OR 2183)"` which translates in English to "Does Table A have a row that has an (any) ID from one of the first three IDs AND (any) one from the second three IDs?"

I'm struggling to wrap my head around finding a way to dynamically generate SQL as the `sentence` becomes more complex.

Suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I find your explanation confusing. First you tell us that we sould interpret AND as OR, beacuse a row cannot have two different ID's at  once, then you say than AND should be intepreted as "AND" to check if a row has different rows?
if an AND is always an OR, then the complex statement reduces to a list of ID's, and everything is just a list of numbers to check :( 43, 44, 47, 2182, 2179, 2183)

Comment: You're going to have to set some ground rules forn your sentences. I.e. tags, keywords, they mean 1 thing, and 1 thing only. Contextual parsing is going to be horrible, and ill advised. You can make a layer of fluff around SQL, but you have to make it as strict as possible, or be prepared to write a lot of parsing code.

Comment: What DBMS are you using (i.e. what version of SQL)?

Comment: You likely got your logic wrong - your statement "Return true if Table A has a row with ID 56 OR row with ID 78" conflicts with explanation. You probably need "Return true if Table A has row with ID 56 AND some other row with ID 78". Sure this doesn't make your parsing any easier.

Comment: @SørenKongstad my apologies, I figured out a clearer way to describe the problem. See updated question.

Comment: @RossPresser PostgreSQL v11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if your `sentences` follow the following rules:

1. A number is a small integer.
2. A term is either a single number, or a set of terms either with AND between each pair, or OR between each pair.
3. Terms must be enclosed by parentheses in order to be combined with more terms.

If this is the case, then I think you can simply:

- replace each number with `(SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_a WHERE id = *number*))`
- Leave any parentheses, ANDs and ORs where they are.
- Enclose the string in one more set of parentheses and prefix `RETURN QUERY`.

This certainly won't be the *simplest* SQL that expresses your `sentence` but I think it will be equivalent.

If you want to optimize more, you can switch `(5 or 6 or 7)` with `(SELECT 1 FROM table_a WHERE id IN (5,6,7))`. But that shouldn't be *necessary* for a correct SQL translation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way

```
  EXECUTE  IMMEDIATE 'SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1
                        FROM table_a
                        WHERE id = :ID1 OR id = :ID2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END'   
            INTO  order_rec
             USING  56, 78;
```

at finally return `order_rec`.
for more information you can [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/improve-sql-query-performance-by-using-bind-variables).